# What does "burning in my loins" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

> Detective, I mean no disrespect, but you are simply ravishing! And in
> this light your hair is like flames **burning in my loins**!

*Learner's Dictionary* gives a definition of **loins** (plural) as the area of a person's body that includes the sexual organs. I hope this doesn't have negative meaning (18+) and you don't mind telling me. I still don't get it. Oh by the way, it's taken from a dialog in a game, *Criminal Case*.

Comment: Either it's awkwardly expressed sexual attraction or a symptom of STD.

Comment: I agree with DrMoishe. _Criminal English_ would be a better name.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik note that the two are not mutually exclusive ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means the speaker is horny; a.k.a. sexually aroused.

Answer (score 6):

When people feel strong emotions - for example anger, shame, embarrassment, sexual or emotional attraction and desire, excitement, fear, among others, they sometimes feel a warm sensation, especially in the face (which may become flushed), and in poetic, figurative, or idiomatic language they may say 'I burned with [anger, shame, etc]'. So when someone says, e.g. 'I felt flames burning in my loins', they don't usually mean that their trousers or skirt are literally on fire. This is a Facebook game. Do not expect good writing in games.

Answer (score 3):

"Loin" is a peculiar word.

It originally meant lower back and hips. It is still used this way when referring to butcher cuts such as "tenderloin" or "loin chops".

In biblical translations, it started being used to refer to sexual anatomy. I assume it was the closest respectable part of the body to those bits which should not be mentioned in polite company.

When used in older literature (as the plural, "loins") it refers to the lower abdomen, between belt and genitals. In this usage, it is a euphemism for genitals, particularly when sexually aroused.

The other common literary reference is "girding one's loins" which means preparing for confrontation. This refers to putting a sword belt around your hips, not around your genitals.

It's best to consider "loins" as either archaic or a sign of purple prose. Except butchers. They can use it as they like.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are aroused sexually. I think loins are referring to all of the large muscles in the genital area. Thighs and buttocks.